# Alternative IDE for Arduino

Tags: c++, linux, arduino

**Is there some alternative IDE for developing for Adruino**

I tried to use Eclipe and Arduino IDE, but i am fan of `Sublime Text`.

So, can i use it for programming for `Arduino or Seeeduino` in Linux?

I mean i must download some libraries and plugged in to my source code?

Comment: I know that is a lot of different IDE's. But i want to understand what of they can work with arduino.

Comment: As long as you can call the compilers from the command line you can use any IDE you want. You will probably have to sacrifice some features tho. The question is what should this new combination of editor + compiler offer to be a viable alternative.

Comment: Yes that is correct question. And i will be glad if somebody can answer on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a [make file](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile), to compile and upload programs to Arduino. You can use any IDE you like (sublime Text in your case and vim in my case)

```
make upload
make screen # to view the serial monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use AVR Studio http://www.atmel.com/microsite/atmel_studio6/

Here is a tutorial on to use it with Arduino:

http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-avr-studio-5-with-arduino-projects/

Comment: Thanks for the shoutout, Markus. We've since updated our tutorial to be compatible with Atmel Studio 6, which brings a lot of improvements. Here's the link: [Using Atmel Studio 6 with Arduino](http://www.engblaze.com/tutorial-using-atmel-studio-6-with-arduino-projects/)

Comment: You suggest a ~1GB IDE to develop for a tiny 32kB processor?

Comment: Yes. It is somewhat surprising how big software is these days. Visual Studio is 5 GB. But IDE's provide a great deal of productivity. Every so often I go back and program a Raspberry Pi on the command line with vi and makefile.s That seems pretty bare bones to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever editor you feel like and build/upload from the command line. Personally, I use [arscons](https://github.com/kylegordon/arscons) to pull this off. You'll need [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), of course. Building is as simple as running

```
$ scons 
$ scons upload
```

at the command line. There are a lot of other options in the `SConstruct` file provided by the arscons project, such as specifying the location for extra libraries; the type of Arduino you're building for; and which USB port you're plugged into. I wasn't able to get wireless programming for an Arduino Fio working with it, but it works great with the Arduino Mega and Uno.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can use Arduino with any IDE if you set up the toolchain properly. If you're looking for a list of possibilities, as well as documentation on how to start on specific platforms, check out the [Development Tools](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DevelopmentTools) section of the Arduino Playground.

To use with Sublime Text, you could adapt one of the existing command-line build scripts to work with Sublime's [build system](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build).

Comment: There is a sublime plugin that completely replaces the arduino IDE https://github.com/Robot-Will/Stino